# React Context Api: Can I have multiple Consumer w/in a single Provider?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

If I have the following nested components:

```
Provider --> Consumer --> Consumer
```

Will I have the same context value across the two Consumers?

Comment: yes and yes. That's the whole idea behind context. The consumers have to be in the same tree which has the Provider somewhere up the tree.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but worth a try.
I have a the same case but for some reason having hard time get it to work. My provider is the "holder of the truth" and its context (state) is being updated by one consumer and used by another. Yet both see what seems to be a different state. @Richard Domingo, did you get it to work? Can you share (at least pseudo) code then? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Pinny, sorry I won't be able to provide some pseudo code. I remember I ended up just using redux anyway. Maybe you could post some question. I'm sure someone will be able to help.